# Electron producing horizontal tearing on large video

Tags: electron

I have a very simple hello-world style Electron app:

**index.html:**

```html
<html>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
<video src="C:\test\very-large-video.mp4" autoplay muted loop width="11520" height="4320" style="object-fit: none"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js:**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

let win

// Tried with and without these switches
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force_high_performance_gpu')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('no-sandbox')
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-renderer-backgrounding')

function createWindow() {
   win = new BrowserWindow({fullscreen: true, titleBarStyle: 'hidden', autoHideMenuBar: true})
   win.loadURL(url.format ({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
   }))
} 

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

If I drop index.html into Chrome or Edge and F11 for fullscreen, it runs perfectly and beautifully. If I run with `electron .\main.js` on the same machine then it consistently produces horizontal tearing and can be easily seen with tall content quickly moving left to right:

[image: horizontal tearing]

Currently running Windows 10 with an NVIDIA A6000.

Does anybody know what could be contributing to the video performance within Electron, and things I could try to mitigate it?